# Question on whether applying L'Hopital's rule is legal

Tags: calculus, limits

I am not sure about this question:

Can we apply L'Hopital's rule for $$\lim_{x\to 0} {f(x)\over g(x)}$$ when $f(x) = {1\over x} + sin{1\over x}$ and $g(x) = {1\over x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. $\lim \frac {f'(x)} {g'(x)}$ does  not exist so you cannot apply L'Hopital's Rule. You can get the limit directly by multiplying the numerator and the denominator by $x$.

Comment: Actually you can apply l'Hopital's rule if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable on an open interval around $0$, but not necessarily for $0$ itself, so you could apply l'Hopital in this situation. You're suggestion for calculating the limit is far more practical though.

Comment: You are wrong. You have to assume that $\lim \frac {f'} {g'}$ exist to apply the rule. In this case $\lim \frac {f'} {g'}$ is $1+\lim \cos(\frac 1 x)$ which does not exist.

Comment: My book does also state that you have to assume $\lim \frac {f'} {g'}$ exists to apply the rule.

Comment: Sorry, just note I made a mistake calculating $f'$, you're absolutely right.